# Which operators work in which stages with MongoDB Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I've been learning the Aggregate framework for about 6 months now.

I often get excited about a new operator. I read about it, I find a use-case, I attempt to use it, and it inevitably fails...

Turns out, that operator is only for the `$project` stage, and I was trying to use it in the `$addField` stage. This isn't explicitly stated anywhere in the operator docs, so it takes several hours of reading Stack Overflow examples before I realize my mistake.

As a part-time Mongo guy (who mostly just dabbles in Aggregate to make my front-end life easier), this is a huge hangup for me. I've read and re-read the MongoDB documentation for at least 30 hours at this point, but I'm still not clear on exactly *which operators* go with *which stages* of the framework.

I'm sure somebody else has encountered this. Is there any kind of quick-reference guide out there?

Comment: _"...  and I was trying to use it in the $newField stage."_ Well,, there is _no_ `$newField` stage in MongoDB Aggregation Framework. See [Aggregation Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html#stages), and [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html#operator-expressions).

Comment: `$addField`... thanks

Comment: Is there really an operator that works in $project but not $addFields?  I've never heard of one.

Answer (score 2):

There are separate sets of operators for [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors), [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators), [aggregation pipeline expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline-operators) and [updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#update-operators)

The [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html#match-aggregation) stage takes a [query document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#query-documents), not an aggregation expression.  But you can embed an aggregation expression in a query document using the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) operator.

The $project, $addFields, and $set stages can use projection and aggregation pipeline operators.

If an aggregation operator can only be used in specific stages, its documentation will list that restriction.  Note that there may be unrelated operators that happen to have the same name.

Examples:
The [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#push-aggregation) aggregation operator documentation says:
`$push is only available in the $group stage.`
But there there is also a [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#push) update operator that can be used with the update* functions.
The arithmetic operator [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#add-aggregation) can be used in any stage that can take an expression.
The [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#first-aggregation-accumulator) accumulator operator can only be used in a $group stage
But the array expression operator [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/#first-aggregation) can be used in any stage where an expression is allowed.